# Need Search two values in one field Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need search for two values in the same field.

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║ Meta_key   ║ Meta_value   ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ first_name ║    pritesh   ║
║  2 ║ last_name  ║    mahajan   ║
║  3 ║ first_name ║    ritesh    ║
║  4 ║ last_name  ║    jain      ║
║  5 ║ first_name ║    john      ║
║  6 ║ last_name  ║    a         ║
║  7 ║ first_name ║    Mambo     ║
║  8 ║ last_name  ║    Nombo     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

This is my table and I want to search all the first names and last names. Below is my query but this does not return what I want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_usermeta` 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name' 
  AND `meta_value` LIKE  '%mahajan%' 
  AND `meta_key` = 'first_name' 
  AND `meta_value` LIKE  '%a%';
```

Comment: You have a number of first names and last names, but how are the first name and last name connected for a single person?

Comment: The query can't work because you're searching for a row which has for the column `Meta_Key` the value `first_name` *and* `last_name` in the same time. It looks like a illformed table structure as firstnames and lastnames aren't linked to each other.

Comment: yes if possible so please check Wordpress  usermeta table.

Comment: This table is wrong designed, I think.

Comment: Without knowing how WP's table structure looks like i think there must be a table which references the meta table from your question. You should take this to connect first- and last names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb96/18)

**Query**:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM 
  (
    (
      SELECT meta_value AS first_name, id AS a_id 
      FROM wp_usermeta 
      WHERE meta_name = 'first_name'
    ) as a
  )
JOIN
  (
    (
      SELECT meta_value AS last_name, id AS b_id 
      FROM wp_usermeta 
      WHERE meta_name = 'last_name'
    ) as b
  )
WHERE a_id = b_id-1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb96/18/0)**:

```
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
|------------|-----------|
|    pritesh |   mahajan |
|     ritesh |      jain |
|       john |         a |
|      Mambo |     Nombo |
```

With this, you can easily search using the two virtual columns `first_name` and `last_name`. You just need to add additional conditions to the `WHERE` clause. something like this:

```
  WHERE a_id = b_id-1
  AND first_name LIKE "%tesh%"
  AND last_name LIKE "%jai%"
```

will produce

```
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
|------------|-----------|
|     ritesh |      jain |
```

**NOTE**

The big assumption I have made here (based on your sample data) is that the **related** `first_name` and `last_name` are always going to have successive `id`'s. (two successive records in the table).

Comment: can you please let me know one more how i add new join because i want to add new join for email ID. Email id is from other table and we will use ID of the existing table for getting email id.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

```
 SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE (`meta_key` = 'last_name' OR `meta_key` = 'first_name' ) and (`meta_value` LIKE  '%mahajan%' OR `meta_value` LIKE  '%a%')
```

Comment: Your condition is "first_name = %mahajan% or first_name = %a% or last_name = %mahajan% or last_name = %a%" in the above query. I don't think this is what the op wants.

Comment: This Query is working but when lastname is getting then it will not search by first name because we are using OR condition..

Answer (score 1):

I think that both rows have to share the same key. Maybe it's `ID`, or `user_id` (not shown in your question?). If this is the case, you could use this query to return the IDs you are looking for:

```
SELECT ID
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE
  (`meta_key` = 'last_name' AND `meta_value` LIKE  '%mahajan%')
  OR (`meta_key` = 'first_name' AND `meta_value` LIKE  '%a%)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

please substitute ID with the actual ID.

Comment: How exactly would `meta_key` be both `first_name` and `last_name` for the same row? You may have meant to put `OR` between the parens. not `AND`.

Comment: Then id isn't a primary key. Is that really how WP does it? Very sloppy DB schema on their part.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder there has to be a primary key, and I think it's ID...but if it is not, there's no way to get what the OP wants, and I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: @fthiella I assume there is a foreign key that the OP is leaving out. Also just to be clear, I wasn't challenging your answer. In fact, with the exception of `GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*)=2`, your SQL seems like what's being asked for. But then again, I'm not the OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     meta_name varchar(20), 
     meta_value varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO wp_usermeta
(meta_name, meta_value)
VALUES
('first_name', 'pritesh'),
('last_name', 'mahajan'),
('first_name', 'ritesh'),
('last_name', 'jain'),
('first_name', 'john'),
('last_name', 'a'),
('first_name', 'Mambo'),
('last_name', 'Nombo');
```

And Query should be like this....

```
SELECT meta_name, meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE 
(meta_name = 'last_name' AND meta_value LIKE  '%mahajan%' )
  OR
(meta_name = 'first_name' AND meta_value LIKE  '%a%');
```